# How to set wxPython grid background color?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working with a wxPython grid, but I cannot set the background color of it (the grid part that isn't filled with cells). I tried with grid.SetBackgroundColour, but without luck; the backcolor shown is always the default system color for windows.

wx.version() -> 2.8.10.1 (msw-unicode)

sys.version  -> 2.5 (r25:51908, Sep 19 2006, 09:52:17) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]

O/S version  -> Windows XP SP3, but I tried with an Ubuntu based Python live cd with the same result.

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class TestFrame (wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, None, title="Grid Table", size=(640,480))

        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self, size=(300,300))
        grid.CreateGrid(2,2)
        grid.SetCellValue(0,0,"1")

        color = (100,100,255)
        attr = self.cellAttr = wx.grid.GridCellAttr()
        attr.SetBackgroundColour(color)

        # for row, col in
        for row in xrange(2):
            for col in xrange(2):
                grid.SetAttr(row, col, attr)

        grid.SetBackgroundColour(color)     # <<< This don't work!

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = TestFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

`grid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour(color)` will color everything, including the area outside the cells.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I missed that between the hundreds of Colors and Colours in the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

use `grid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour(grid.GetLabelBackgroundColour())` to color everything the same colour. The grid can then be repainted on cell basis.

Answer (score 0):

Working Snippet from @Rolf of Saxony's

[wx grid SetCellBackGroundColor() is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477826/10789707)

based on @interjay's and @jake77 above answers:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


    class MyForm(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Sample grid")
    
            self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
            self.grid.CreateGrid(5, 4)
            self.grid.SetCellSize(4, 1, 1, 2)
    
            self.grid.SetDefaultCellAlignment(wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    
            # self.grid.SetColLabelSize(0)            # eliminates spreadsheet-style row & col headers
            # self.grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
    
            self.grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(4, 3, wx.LIGHT_GREY)
    
            rowHeight = 50
            colWidth = 50
            for i in range(1, 5):
                self.grid.SetRowSize(i, rowHeight)
            for i in range(0, 4):
                self.grid.SetColSize(i, colWidth)
    
            self.grid.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.GridLeftClick, self.grid)
    
        def GridLeftClick(self, event):
            col = event.GetCol()
            row = event.GetRow()
            clr = self.grid.GetCellBackgroundColour(row, col)
            if clr != wx.LIGHT_GREY:
                self.grid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(wx.WHITE))
                self.grid.SetLabelBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(wx.WHITE))
            else:
                self.grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(row, col, wx.GREEN)
            self.Refresh()
    
    
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And 2nd snippet only partially working — the headers and row labels display all right but not the cells (feel free to fix it if you will!):

From [wxPython: Grid Tips and Tricks](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/04/wxpython-grid-tips-and-tricks/)

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Grid Color Bg")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(7, 5)
        self.grid.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK, self.colorBg)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def colorBg(self, event):
        """"""

        clr = self.grid.GetDefaultCellBackgroundColour()

        clr1 = self.grid.GetLabelBackgroundColour()

        if clr != wx.Colour(wx.WHITE):
            self.grid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour(
                self.grid.SetLabelBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(wx.WHITE))
            )

        if clr1 != wx.Colour(wx.WHITE):
            self.grid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(wx.WHITE))


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```